# Using jQuery .click works but .touchstart desn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, touch

I have a block of working code that allows me to shift from one set of colored items to another based on a span click event that runs in jQuery. I am using wordpress and it requires I spell out jQuery instead of using '$'.  In part, it works by moving a variable to the active selection and changing a variety of other properties based on defined variables in the html of that 'span'

I tried changing `.click(function f()...` to `.touchstart(function f()...` and it doesn't work when I load the site on mobile. If you think you know the answer, cool. I will now list things I have tried.

This is what my click function looks like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function f($) {
jQuery('.changecolor span').click(function f($) {...
});
});
```

Attempts:

```
jQuery('.changecolor span').touchstart(function e()
jQuery('.changecolor span').on("tap", function e() {...
```

My cache is set to auto clear every time I save a new change in, and I've tested this.

Comment: See jQuery [trigger()](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.changecolor span').on('touchstart',function(ev) {
    $('your seletor').trigger(ev);
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I want to thank you. In the end the reason my code was not functioning was because I had my ready function like this
'''
 JQuery(document).ready(function touch(e) {
'''
instead of like this
'''
 jQuery(document).ready(function touch(e) {
'''

It was a capitalized J in the end, but your comment gave me the confidence that what I had was right to look for this tiny error. Thanks again. Now I just have to figure out why this is working in my developer debug on the browser but not on my phone...